# prometheus server on kubernetes, gcp not responding

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, networking

Environment:

- Google Cloud Engine
- installed kubernetes with kubeadm on GCE

try to install Prometheus server on the k8s env.

reference: https://github.com/prometheus-operator/kube-prometheus/tree/main

```
git clone https://github.com/prometheus-operator/kube-prometheus/tree/main
cd kube-prometheus
kubectl create -f manifests/setup/
kubectl create -f manifests

vi manifests/grafana-service.yaml  # type: LoadBalancer 
vi manifests/alertmanager-service.yaml  # type: LoadBalancer 
vi manifests/prometheus-service.yaml  # type: LoadBalancer 
kubectl apply -f manifests/grafana-service.yaml
kubectl apply -f manifests/alertmanager-service.yaml
kubectl apply -f manifests/prometheus-service.yaml
```

Output:

```
kubectl get po -n monitoring
>> all pods are running 

kubectl get svc -n monitoring
prometheus-k8s          LoadBalancer   10.32.0.36   34.64.234.16   9090:31333/TCP,8080:32469/TCP   42m
```

But, the request(http://34.64.234.16:9090) gives no response.
So, I opened all ports for worker nodes.
But got same response.